# Javascript match and extract $ symbol from a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I have:

```
var price = '$4000';
var currency = price.match([\$]);
alert(currency);
```

However this doesn't seem to work. I would like to extract the $ symbol and compare it, if true then fetch some currency comparison and compare currency. What is the correct way to extract symbols via regex?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to check if there is a Dollar-sign inside your string, replace it with "nothing" ($4000 >> 4000) or know it's position? It's kind of odd you want to "extract" the Dollar-sign ;)

Comment: *"I would like to extract the $ symbol and compare it"* What do you mean "compare"?

Comment: basically I would like to have like this `if (currency === '$') {perform functions};` like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work: `'$4000'.match(/^\$/)`.

(It looks for the `$` sign at the beginning of the string)

The javascript syntax for regular expression literal uses `/` at the beginning and at the end of the expression.

Comment: Thanks CD, that works great! Could you please explain why the brackets doesn't work? I read here http://regexone.com/lesson/15? that the [\$] should work

Comment: it would work like this: `/[\$]/` witch is a regular expression literal.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to find the dollar sign in any position use:

```
var currency = price.match(/\$/);
```

If you want to find the dollar sign at the beginning of the string use:

```
var currency = price.match(/^\$/);
```

Here's the documentation about [Javascript RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 3):

Put your regular expression inside `//` or quotes:

```
var price = '$4000';
var currency = price.match(/[\$]/);
alert(currency);
```

Answer (score 3):

Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. (c) Jamie Zawinski

I agree that RegEx is more concise but you could do with just `'$4000'.indexOf('$')`. Like this:

```
if (price.indexOf('$')>-1) { currency = '$' }
```

Comment: Actually, `currency = '$'` would be enough :)

Comment: True :) Edited accordingly.